# Whether I extend the AdminUser should inherit from AbstractUser?

Tags: python, django

Previous, I extend the AdminUser from AbstractUser:

```
class AdminUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=40)  # sha1加密
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)  # 手机号码

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

You see I use the `is_staff` and `is_superuser` to define whether is a admin user.

But, today when I read the [Django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user): 
There is UserAdmin :

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
```

Whether I was wrong to subclass from AbstractUser? whether I should inherit from  UserAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize admin user model you should make this separate `UserAdmin` class, but if you want to subclass all the users you have with it, it's not the best idea, because not all your users behave like admin. So, the `AbstractUser` looks good. 
FYI, there is no `BaseUserAdmin` in Django, the `as` syntax says this name
should be an `alias` for `UserAdmin` class within this file.